# Prevent no session fails in case of passing JPA repo methods

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

What is the way to prevent the fail of **no session** using JPA repository in below case:

I have a class called X with relation `@OneToMany` with `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`to class Y. I create the whole method in a repository, then I pass it to the Service class, and after that, I pass it to the Controller.

While I want to get the object Y from class X by `x.getY()` which is related via `Lazy` fetchType I get an error (from Hibernate) called **no session**.

How can I prevent this error from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to enclose the `x.getY()` call inside your `@Transactional` method or to move the transaction boundaries higher up in the call hierarchy, so that invocation is included as well.

In general i would not move higher than the service so if you access that property for the first time in the Controller for example then other possible options would be to:

- Eagerly fetch all the required dependencies while the session is still opened (join fetch)
- Use `Hibernate.initialize(x.getY());` inside of the transactional context
- Call `size` method on the depenedent colletions to initialze them `x.getY().size`.

Comment: I would tend to use the `@Transactional`, but please tell me if I am correct - I need to use `import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;`?

Comment: Yes exactly. You have to remember though that you have to use additional config (package scanning and transaction management). Check out http://www.baeldung.com/transaction-configuration-with-jpa-and-spring

Comment: Even when I use spring boot?

Comment: If the transactional annotated classes are in the  package hierarchy under the SpringBootConfiguration, then you dont need to define anything. If not use @ComponentScan